# Unable to add datagridview to a dynamically created Tab

Tags: c#, datagridview, tabcontrol

I'm trying to add datagridview in selected tab. I didn't got any compilation errors but the grid view is not appearing in my tab pages.

Below is my code:

```
if (tbPerasaan2.Controls[0] == tbPerasaan2.SelectedTab)
{
    for (int Tabcount = 0; Tabcount < tbPerasaan2.SelectedIndex; Tabcount++)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable data = new DataTable();
        DataGridView dgJPerasaan = new DataGridView();
        //this.tbPerasaan2.SelectedTab
        TabPage t = tbPerasaan2.TabPages[0];
        tbPerasaan2.SelectedTab = t;
        t.Controls.Add(dgJPerasaan);
        //  this.Controls.Add(dgJPerasaan);
        dgJPerasaan.DataSource = data;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need something like this : tbPerasaan2.TabPages[0].Controls.Add(dgJPerasaan);

Comment: Thank you @Stanley

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create datagridview in tabpage1 then replace *Tabcount < tabControl1.SelectedIndex* with *Tabcount <= tabControl1.SelectedIndex* because 
*if (tbPerasaan2.Controls[0]* is the tabpage1 of tabcontrol. So it always results tabpage1.

```
if (tbPerasaan2.Controls[0] == tbPerasaan2.SelectedTab) //tbPerasaan2.Controls[0] results tabpage1
{
   for (int Tabcount = 0; Tabcount <= tbPerasaan2.SelectedIndex; Tabcount++)
   {
       DataSet ds = new DataSet();
       DataTable data = new DataTable();
       DataGridView dgJPerasaan = new DataGridView();
       //this.tbPerasaan2.SelectedTab
       TabPage t = tbPerasaan2.TabPages[0];
       tbPerasaan2.SelectedTab = t;
       t.Controls.Add(dgJPerasaan);
       //  this.Controls.Add(dgJPerasaan);
       dgJPerasaan.DataSource = data;
    }
}
```

It will create datagridview in tabpage1.

Comment: Thank you. That helps a lot!